# How to change default editor for crontab in CentOS7?

Tags: linux, centos, cron, centos7, nano

I want to change the default editor on my CentOS 7 box for crontab as it currently launches vi and I prefer nano.

I have read a lot of pages online which suggest running `export EDITOR='nano'` or some similar - some places seem to suggest double quotes (`"`), others no quotes at all.

In any case, none of these approaches are working, I run the `export` command, then `sudo crontab -e` and still it launches vi! What am I doing wrong?

I realise that if I want the change to persist between sessions, I need to place this `export` command into my `bashrc` or `bash_profile` file, or create a .sh file in `/etc/profile.d/`, but I just want to get it working in isolation first before I make it persistent - can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The export works like you see, but if you use sudo, you're running crontab as other user, in this case as root, then you need set EDITOR as root too.

(I post as answer because I can't comment)

Comment: Of course, what a moron I am! Thanks for that, now that I'm also running crontab as the current user, this is working fine.

Answer (score 11):

You can use -E with sudo

> -E' The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment
>   variables. The security policy may return an error if the -E option is
>   specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the
>   environment.

```
export EDITOR=nano
sudo -E crontab -e
```

Comment: Great, thanks for that - combined with the answer from Carlos I now understand why this was not working as I expected.